# How to make multiple slideshows on one page with javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css, slideshow

W3Schools has great [javascript slideshow](http://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_slideshow.asp) with fading and elegant css that I want to use for my project and works great as a single slideshow. Could someone show me how I would modify this script to allow for multiple slideshows on one page that operate independent of one another?

Answer (score 0):

You will just need to duplicate some HTML and some CSS directly from the example code for each new slideshow you want. Provide the additional images, then alter the CSS positions of new prev. and next buttons. Below I have made some changes to the example code for what your new slideshow will require in addition to the first example.

```
<div class="newslideshow-container">
<div class="mySlides fade">
<div class="numbertext">1 / 3</div>
<img src="img4.jpg" style="width:100%">
<div class="newtext">Caption Text</div>
</div>

<div class="mySlides fade">
<div class="newnumbertext">2 / 3</div>
<img src="img5.jpg" style="width:100%">
<div class="newtext">Caption Two</div>
</div>

<div class="mySlides fade">
<div class="newnumbertext">3 / 3</div>
<img src="img6.jpg" style="width:100%">
<div class="newtext">Caption Three</div>
</div>

<a id ="prev" class="prev" onclick="plusSlides(-1)">&#10094;</a>
<a id ="next" class="next" onclick="plusSlides(1)">&#10095;</a>
</div>
<br>

<div style="text-align:center">
<span class="dot" onclick="currentSlide(1)"></span> 
<span class="dot" onclick="currentSlide(2)"></span> 
<span class="dot" onclick="currentSlide(3)"></span> 
</div>
```

----------CSS--------------------------

```
  /* Next & previous buttons */
  #prev, #next {
  cursor: pointer;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  width: auto;
  margin-top: -22px;
  padding: 16px;
  color: white;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 18px;
  transition: 0.6s ease;
  border-radius: 0 3px 3px 0;
}

  /* Position the "next button" to the right */
  #next {
  right: 0;
  border-radius: 3px 0 0 3px;

  /* Caption text */
  .newtext {
  color: #f2f2f2;
  font-size: 15px;
  padding: 8px 12px;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 8px;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
}

/* Number text (1/3 etc) */
.newnumbertext {
  color: #f2f2f2;
  font-size: 12px;
  padding: 8px 12px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
}
```

You will need to adjust the CSS properties "top", "bottom" and "right" to the  positions you want for the new slideshows.